# How can I check if one list is a subset of the another?

Tags: python

Here is the current code I have:

```
a = input('Enter words: ') 
b, c = a.split()
q = []
z = [] 

for i in b: 
    q.append(i)
for j in c: 
    z.append(j)

for letters in q: 
    if letters in z: 
        print('yes')
```

It will output `'yes'` if the `letter` in `q` is also in `z`.

Is there someway to check if all instances of characters in one list are in another. Like:

```
for letters in q: 
    if all letters in z: #all
        print('yes')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = [3, 4, 5]

set(lst1).issubset(lst2)
# False
lst1 = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = [1, 2, 3]
set(lst1).issubset(lst2)
# True
```

Comment: The second suggestion doesn't do quite the same thing. (It checks if both lists contain exactly the same members rather than checking for a subset.)

Comment: @smarx it's actually not right at all because 'sort()' doesn't return anything.

Comment: Excellent point. :-) `sorted(lst1) == sorted(lst2)` would be a little better but still suffer from the issue in my first comment.

Comment: `lst1.sort() == lst2.sort()` should just be `lst1 == lst2`, but please just delete that whole section of your answer, since it doesn't help with the question that was asked. :-)

Comment: This approach also works when lst1 is an empty list, as that is also a subset.  Furthermore when both lists are empty.  I like the elegance of handling edge cases so simply.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
if all(letter in z for letter in q):
    print('yes')
```

Simplified full working code:

```
q, z = input('Enter words: ').split()

if all(letter in z for letter in q):
    print('yes')
```

Sample runs:

```
$ python test.py
Enter words: cat tack
yes
$ python test.py
Enter words: cat bat
```